# How can I group a block of code in Python, similar to function, but without the need to define the parameters?

Tags: python, function

How can I group a block of code in Python, similar to a function but without the need to define the parameters?

For example, the block is like this:

```cpp
code_block() {
    c = a + b
}
```

I want to use it in code like this:

```
a = 2
b = 3
code_block()
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use global variables inside your function and initialise `c`

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 0

def code_block():
    global a, b, c
    c = b + a

code_block()
print(c)
```

From the documentation: [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within
>   the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly
>   declared as global.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the variables are visible from the scope of the function declaration, you can define yourself a function without parameters that can operate on these values:

```
x = 0
y = 1
def add():
    return x+y
print(add())
```

Note that the scope creates an implicit copy of these values, i.e. it is not possible to manipulate the values outside of the function, i.e.

```
x = 0
def manipulate():
    x = 1
manipulate()
print(x)
```

will still return 0. A nice read is [this article](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

Comment: As ScottMcC in his answer noted, you can also manipulate the variables outside, if you define them as `global`.

Comment: My script requires me to use `print(add())` after the `y=1` statement. So, if I do `def add():` before `x=1` variable is not defined error and if I do it after, the function is not defined error will show.